# boost serialization on objects containing other objects ponted to by unique_ptr

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, unique-ptr

I have an object of the class A which is a composition of several other objects from different classes X, Y, Z, ... Those classes are pointed to through unique_ptr. Lets assume that the sub classes X, Y, Z only have primitive data types.

I am trying to serialize my objects and so I added a save and load method to class A. For the primitive data types members of class A this works out.

```
// Class A HPP:
private:
int m_classXID{};
std::unique_ptr<Class_X> m_classXObject;

...
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const;

template<class Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version);

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version);
...
```

Implementation:

```
// Class A CPP:
...
template<class Archive>
void Class_A::save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const
{
    ar << m_classXID;
}

template<class Archive>
void Class_A::load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar >> m_classXID;
}

template<class Archive>
void Class_A::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    boost::serialization::split_member(ar, *this, 1);
}
...
```

Now I wanted to go one step further and tryed to implement for one of the sub classes the serialization.

What I did is that I added the following code for instance to the class X:

```
// Class X HPP:
private:
// Gives the serialization infrastructure access to the serialize function!
friend class boost::serialization::access;
// Archive
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version);
```

Implementataion part:

```
// Class X CPP:
template <typename Archive>
void Class_X::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& m_firstInt;
    ar& m_secondInt;
    ar& m_thirdInt;
    ar& m_fourthInt;
    ...;
}
```

Now I am completly confused on how to deal with the implementation part of the save and load methods of Class A.

I tried a lot cant even remeber what. What I am currently on looks like the following:

```
template<class Archive>
void Class_A::save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const
{
    ar << m_classXID;
    ar << m_classXObject;
}

template<class Archive>
void Class_A::load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar >> m_classXID;
    m_classXObject = std::make_unique<Class_X>();
    ar >> m_classXObject;
}

template<class Archive>
void Class_A::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    boost::serialization::split_member(ar, *this, 1);
}
```

But I get a big cryptpic error message from Microsoft Visual Studio regarding "unresolved external symbol... LINK2019. I wanted to have my approach reviewed. The LINK error is not my main concern.

**UPDATE**: Thank a lot for the hint with the template!! -> only in header. This would have taken me a few days to sort out! So thanks a lot!! Moving everything to the header files solved the issue.

Comment: "I wanted to have my approach reviewed. The LINK error is not my main concern." if the link error is not the concern, why mention it at all? QUestions are best received when they are specific and focused. If the question talks about a linker error, then we will help you with the linker error. Reviews on the other hand are considered offtopic

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).